# Mongoose finding entry in sub document, with multiple fields?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a schema of the following structure, which where users can vote on their happiness level of the content. We now need to know which happiness level the user voted for.

The easy solution is to get the document back and then iterate over each array and find where a vote corresponding to the user exists, though it isn't very optimal.

```
const VoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

const DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    text: String,
    happiness: {
        '-2': [VoteSchema],
        '-1': [VoteSchema],
        '0': [VoteSchema],
        '1': [VoteSchema],
        '2': [VoteSchema]
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

I have also tried the following, but there does not appear to be a `find()` function on the object (CoreMongooseArray):

```
const doc = await Document.findOne({ _id: id }).populate('createdBy');
doc.happiness['-1'].find({ user: userId })
```

Ideally I would be looking for a way to do a query and have a 'virtual' field 'myHappinessVote' created, but I am not sure how to go about this.

Can anyone suggest an approach to this problem, without changing the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion and analysis, changing the schema was the way to go, even though we didn't originally want to, especially when we consider max object sizes. This also had the benefit of simplifying the queries, and making the logic more understandable.

We ended up creating a schema of the form:

```
const DocumentVoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    document: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Document' },
    voteBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    happiness: Number
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

This allowed for searches queries of the form:

```
const docs = await DocumentVote.find({ happiness: value }).populate('voteBy');
const docs = await DocumentVote.find({ document: docId }).populate('voteBy');
```